# Can’t assign to delegate an anonymous method with less specific parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I’m able to assign a method `M` to delegate object `d` with a less specific parameter type, but when I want to assign an anonymous method with same the signature as method `M` to `d`, I get an error.

Why is that?

```
class derivedEventArgs : EventArgs { }

delegate void newDelegate(object o, derivedEventArgs e); 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    newDelegate d = M; // ok
                d = (object o, EventArgs e) => { }; // error
}

public static void M(object o, EventArgs e) { }
```

Comment: You certainly have some interesting naming conventions going on there...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Jared is of course correct that this is by design.

The reason for that design is that in the contravariant method conversion case, you might have a method that you didn't write, and be assigning it to a delegate variable that you didn't write either. You don't control the types. So we go a bit easy on you and let the parameters match contravariantly and the return types match covariantly.

In the lambda-to-delegate conversion, you *do* control the thing being assigned. There is nothing *stopping* you from making it an exact match in the parameter types and therefore we *require* you to. No fudging allowed here.

Comment: Great answers.Thank you both for helping me out

Answer (score 17):

This is covered in section 6.5 of the C# language specification.  If you explicitly type the parameters of an anonymous function, they must match in both type and modifiers in order to be compatible signatures.

> Specifically, a delegate type D is compatible with an anonymous function F provided
>
> ...
>
> If F has an explicitly typed parameter list, each parameter in D has the same type and modifiers as the corresponding parameter in F.

Answer (score 3):

While you have got your answer, I will provide a workaround if this is *required*. Say, all you got is a delegate of signature `(object, EventArgs)` in which case you want to convert it to your `newDelegate` type, you could do:

```
SomeDelegate p = (object o, EventArgs e) => { }; //comes from somewhere
NewDelegate d = (o, e) => p(o, e); //can rewrite like this
```

Alternately with generics and (contra) variance feature of generic delegates, you can do it with one delegate type:

```
delegate void NewDelegate<in T>(object o, T e) where T : EventArgs;

//then
NewDelegate<EventArgs> p = (object o, EventArgs e) => { }; //comes from somewhere
NewDelegate<DerivedEventArgs> d = p; //straightforward assignable - contravariance
```